# Access csv cell in Lightning and Visualforce pages

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I have uploaded a csv file as static resource in my Salesforce org. Now, I want to access data/record from that csv file for my custom component in either Custom component in Lightning Experience or Visualforce pages.

For example, if `Name` is `C`, I want to display `ID = 32`. 
How can I refer `B4` for cell `A4`? I can refer the entire csv file as an image:

`<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.myZipFile, imageVar)}"/>`

But, I need to refer individual cells. I understand I need to bind cell id with the condition I want to meet, but how?

I was trying to use Data Loader, but with data loader I can't access a record in an individual cell.

[image]